# Sample size required

Tags: biostatistics

I want to test ALS patients and want to compare a specific feature=csf. I have a population size (N = 128) and I used an R function to calculate it:

`sample.size.prop(e=0.05, P = 0.15, N = 128, level = 0.95)`

If I want to create two groups from the sample size that i got and compare between them (min log fold change= 15%), is it correct to divide the number I got in the previous function?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure your population is 128 people? If yes, then you can collect data on all the 128 people and you don't need to do any testing or statistics since you will know everything about the whole population.

Comment: I want to randomly take out of these 128 people 2 groups (2 different levels of the disease) and check for a difference. I want to know what is the minimum size I need for a group in order for it to work.

Comment: 128 people in the whole world suffer from this disease?

Comment: No, but this is the data I'm working on

Comment: So your population is not 128. 128 samples is already a small dataset, why not use it all?

Comment: Basically, this is a very specific experiment and we refer to 128 as the whole population (although there are more patients than that). We tested 5 different times and not all patients were tested each time because patients died during the experiment. So 128 is the number of patients we tested during the trial period and out of that number I want to divide into groups of different levels of the disease.

Comment: So your sample size is 128. Why not call it a sample? I fear you may be thinking about this wrong in a fundamental way, as "sample" is pretty standard terminology.

Comment: You need to give us more details about your data and the methodology, it’s impossible to answer otherwise. If 128 is your population this means that the conclusions you’ll draw will apply only to those 128 people.